# application.match use when looking up in an array

Tags: arrays, vba

I am using application match to look for a value in an array: it finds it, but is always returning the index incorrectly.  The index numbers are always 1 greater than they should be, so if the match was found and the index should be 1, it returns 2.

pos = Application.Match(namecat, YearlyCatname, False)

Any suggestions?

Comment: Match is one-based. And it's slow with arrays. You can use a loop.

Comment: @BigBen see [THIS](https://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2011/10/26/match-vs-find-vs-variant-array-vba-performance-shootout/) As I understand it, if the goal is to return only 1 answer(non looped) then MATCH is the quickest.  If in a loop then correct looping an array is quicker.  So it depends

Comment: @ScottCraner - I knew about that link but I don't think I ever read it closely, lol. OP: if you want to use match, then you can adjust its result depending on the `LBound` of the array.

Comment: One line of code doesn't give us much clue as to *why* you think Match is returning the wrong result.  Are you looking directly at the value of `pos`, or using it for something else and the problem is then "downstream"

Answer (score 1):

As already stated, Match is slow with arrays and looping whilst maybe faster is still going to be a bit slow on large arrays.

You could join the array to a string, find the location of the value, chop the string based on the location, split it back to an array then count the ubound of the new array like this:

```
Sub FindValue()
Dim MyArr As Variant, ResultAddress As Long
MyArr = Array("Hello", "World", "!!!", "Some", "test", "data")
ResultAddress = FindInArray(MyArr, "Some", "|")
MsgBox "Found search value: """ & MyArr(ResultAddress) & """ at index value: " & ResultAddress
End Sub

Function FindInArray(MyArr As Variant, MyValue As String, MyDelimeter As String)
Dim StringArr As String, MyValueAddress As Long, TempArr As Variant
StringArr = Join(MyArr, MyDelimeter)
MyValueAddress = InStr(1, StringArr, MyDelimeter & MyValue & MyDelimeter)
StringArr = Left(StringArr, MyValueAddress)
TempArr = Split(StringArr, MyDelimeter)
FindInArray = UBound(TempArr)
End Function
```

I made the delimeter a parameter of the function so you can pass in something that you are sure will not be in your data.

You can add some error checking in there to make sure the value is found before continuing in the function. You could also add into the function a way to count the occurences of the match value and alert the user if it exists more than once.

Comment: Thank you!  both options worked, looping and the function.  Appreciate the responses.

Comment: I found an issue when the array has only one item (I was using it to create a "map like" array where I look for the value before inserting). If you make this change, it works for arrays with a single value: `StringArr = MyDelimeter + Join(MyArr, MyDelimeter) + MyDelimeter`